# code for addition of two binary numbers using quantum computing without error

Tags: python, qiskit

i want a code for quantum computing that performs the addition of two binary numbers using Qiskit but it is showing error that is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Cell In[2], line 1
    from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile, assemble, Aer, execute
ImportError: cannot import name 'Aer' from 'qiskit' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/__init__.py)

Use %tb to get the full traceback.
```

please share a code that performs any mathematical operation using quantum computing

Comment: Soo... Python 2 or 3?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, there's no `Aer` in the `qiskit` module.

Comment: There's a [`qiskit-aer`](https://pypi.org/project/qiskit-aer/) module, is that what you wanted?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: qiskit restructured modules in a version release https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ibm-provider/blob/6be5f3297ede75bb062b20601058b55a397668e3/docs/tutorials/Migration_Guide_from_qiskit-ibmq-provider.ipynb